# Google Sheets filter values by value type

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for help to create a filter on Google Sheets Script.
I want the following:

- I have a database Schedule which has table with information that I want to filter
- Once the database A is updated I want to filter Colum b row 8 and only take the cells that have information and are filled with words, numbers, etc.
- After that I want to copy the data filtered and paste on a new Sheet Data “Foreman on specific columns
- Also, I want to copy and paste the format such as color, size, etc.
- I have the following code which it does the partial job but I cannot figure it out to only get the specific data needed

```
function Foreman(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var scheduleCCC_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Schedule");
  var Foreman_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Foreman");
  var pasteforemans = Foreman_sheet.getRange(8,2);
  var originalData = scheduleCCC_sheet.getRange(9,2,scheduleCCC_sheet.getLastRow()1,11).getValues();
  var filter1 ="";
  Foreman_sheet.getRange(8,2,Foreman_sheet.getLastRow(),11).clearContent().clearFormat();
  var data = originalData.filter(filterlogic);

  Foreman_sheet.getRange(9,2,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

}

var filterlogic = function(item){
  if(item[1] == ""){
    return false;
  }else {
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Hi there, what do you mean by "only get the specific data needed"? What issues are you encountering with the code you have? @user247560

Comment: Hi, I meant with "the specific data" is when I use the filter to only copy the data I filtered; the code is not copying the data filter is coping all the data. I can give you access to the file if you want; please share an email; thank you

Comment: Can you please share a link of your sheet and offer a more detailed/accurate version of what you are trying to achieve? @user247560

Comment: Here is the link; https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kThF7eMKgKNWNxS-lupCRG_iuC9SMjFkzDFDJ38h0QM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay thank you, and can you please explain once again what is the issue? And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are two tabs; Tab Schedule CCC, I want to be able to filter the cell "B8" only the cells with content, copy the filtered information with content and then copy on the tab Foreman "B9" also the format.

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter the values based on the condition that the cells are not empty, you can use the below snippet of code:

#### Snippet

```
function myFunction() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_OF_THE_SS").getSheetByName("Schedule CCC");
   var otherss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_OF_THE_SS").getSheetByName("Foreman");
   var range = ss.getRange("START_ROW", "START_COL", ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn());
   var filter = range.getFilter();
   var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenCellNotEmpty().build();
   filter.setColumnFilterCriteria("COL_POSITION", filterCriteria);
   for (var i = 1; i <= ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
      if (ss.isRowHiddenByFilter(i) == false) {
         ss.getRange("RANGE_FROM_THE_CCC_SHEET").copyTo(otherss.getRange("RANGE_FROM_THE_FOREMAN_SHEET"));
      }
   }
}
```

#### Explanation

The above code gathers the filter from the source sheet and sets it the `whenCellNotEmpty` criteria. Afterwards it loops through the data and checks if a specific row is *hidden* by the filter; if the result of this is `false`, then it copies the row with its format onto the destination sheet. The format of the row is preserved by using the `copyTo` method.

#### Note

You will need to adjust the ranges to match the ones in your sheet and might need to add another condition when looping through the data from the source sheet.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Sheet Class - isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition);
- [Apps Script Filet Class - setColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition, filterCriteria)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#setcolumnfiltercriteriacolumnposition,-filtercriteria);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet).